# meaning of "Twas" and given sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Context:

> Amazing grace, How sweet the sound
>   That saved a wretch like me.
>   I once was lost, but now am found, 
>   Was blind, but now I see.
>
> **'Twas grace that taught my heart to fear,** 
>   And grace my fears relieved.
>   How precious did that grace appear
>   The hour I first believed.

What does **'Twas** in this sentence means? And what about: *And grace my fears relieved*?

Comment: Googling for 'twas, I immediately got **[this result](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%27twas)** - a dictionary record with a definition.

Comment: "and grace my fears relieved" means "and grace relieved my fears". The word order is changed to suit the poetic metre and make the sentence more expressive.

Comment: You're welcome! ‘Twas not a big deal. (0:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**'Twas** is a contraction of **it was.**